# How to create the sandbox account on amazon seller central

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to create the sandbox account on amazon seller account and developer account on amazon MWS. Please provide the detailed steps for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amazon doesn't provide sandbox account.you need to create live seller account for mws integration.

Comment: This is no longer the case. Amazon now offers sandboxed environments.